# Can I 'un-raid' my raid 1 setup

Tags: windows-vista, raid1

My dell T7400 has two 300G 15k SAS drives in a raid 1 configuration. I'd like to instead have a 300G 'C" drive and a 300G 'D' drive.

Is there anyway to remove one of the drives from the raid configuration without having to reinstall the OS? and then reformat and use the second hard drive as a new disk?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sure can.

the raid config'd through windows, or a HW controller?

Comment: Hardware controller, sas 1068e

Comment: yeah backup, turn off PC, then just pull one of drives. start PC, get into the controller settings and remove the absent disk from array.

Even if you make a mistake, you'll have the data on the removed disk, and then you can blow away the array, and stick both disks in and you'll have two JBODs.

Answer (score 1):

Reboot and look for a RAID BIOS/config option (F7, etc) key will depend on RAID controller. Within the RAID BIOS you can most likely re-configure the virtal disk to be a single disk instead of two mirrored disks. This will clear the way to reformating the second drive within windows disk management interface as drive d.
The specifics are dependent on the RAID controller, see their sites support section for limitations. Backup first!